# How android application synchronize data with backend server?

Tags: android

Backend server has tables, and the android client have the same tables. Are there any way to synchronize data between them?

Answer (score 1):

From your question I understand that There are tables on mobile and server both are same. Now you want to take a data from server from mobile and from to Server. Use upload and Download. When your application get started download the data from the server Process on that data after that upload that data to the server. so that both your mobile and server db remain updated.

for upload and download you can use following links:

http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

You have to use the JSON.

Comment: There have two situation: net work fine, and the mobile can't connect net. In two case, we should ensure Data Consistent between server and mobile client.
For example: when server data changed, How to synchronize data to mobile client.                                                    When client data changed, send a request to server to update data.

Comment: For that you have to use services and Broad cast receiver . Services keeps track on whether your data is changing and once data get change broadcast receiver send data back to the server.

Comment: Can you give me more detail, how services keeps track on  whether your data is changing .